# Common values from the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I have one table as PCity, where there are 2 attributes as shown below:
I am using MySQL.

```
City    Year
A   2017
B   2017
C   2017
A   2018
B   2018
C   2018
A   2019
B   2019
C   2019
A   2020
B   2020
D   2020
E   2020
F   2020
```

I want to get only that cities which are present in all the years:

```
City    Year
A   2017
B   2017
A   2018
B   2018
A   2019
B   2019
A   2020
B   2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by city) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt = (select count(distinct year) from mytable)
```

This requires MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions, one alternative uses subqueries:

```
select *
from mytable t
where (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.city = t.city)
    = (select count(distinct year) from mytable)
```

If there were duplicates in the table (unlike what your sample data shows), you would use `count(distinct year)` in the first subquery instead of `count(*)`.